# Having request processing failure when running Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a webapp using Spring MVC and Hibernate, but I'm stucking on some error and I couldn't resolve it by myself. Thanks for any help.

The full exception stack:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/MyWebapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mywebapp.dao.model.impl.MySqlPetDao.getAllPets(MySqlPetDao.java:92)
    at mywebapp.controller.PetController.getAllPets(PetController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import mywebapp.dao.MySqlDaoFactory;
import mywebapp.dao.model.impl.MySqlPetDao;
import mywebapp.dao.model.interfaces.PetDao;
import mywebapp.model.Pet;


@RequestMapping(value="pet.htm")
public class PetController  {

    @Autowired
    private PetDao petDao;

    public PetDao getPetDao() {
        return petDao;
    }

    public void setPetDao(PetDao petDao) {
        this.petDao = petDao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAllPets() throws Exception {

        List<Pet> petList = getPetDao().getAllPets();

        return new ModelAndView("petInfo","petList",petList);
    }

}
```

My PetDaoImpl:

```
package mywebapp.dao.model.impl;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import mywebapp.dao.model.interfaces.PetDao;
import mywebapp.model.Pet;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

@Repository
public class MySqlPetDao implements PetDao {

    private Session currentSession;

    private Transaction currentTransaction;

    public Session openCurrentSession() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void closeCurrentSession() {
        currentSession.close();
    }

    public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sessionFactory;

    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;

    }

    public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;

    }

    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return currentTransaction;

    }

    public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
        this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Pet> getAllPets() {
        List<Pet> pets = (List<Pet>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Pet").list();
        return pets;
    }

    @Override
    public Pet getPet(int petId) {
        //some other code
    }

}
```

Finally, my Configuration and context-setup, I used the java class and annotation to build up the configuration:

```
package mywebapp.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import mywebapp.controller.PetController;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="mywebapp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class PetControllerConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getView() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver view = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        view.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        view.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        view.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return view;
    }

    @Bean
    public PetController getPetObj(){
        return new PetController();
    }
}
```

Context:

```
package mywebapp.config;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import mywebapp.controller.PetController;
import mywebapp.model.Pet;

public class SpringAppContext implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(PetControllerConfig.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(PetControllerConfig.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("*.htm");
}
```

}

If you need any more information from me, please let me know. Any hint will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `getCurrentSession()` returns `null`, didn't you forget to call `openSession()`?

Comment: You are using Spring then use Spring to configure hibernate. I suggest a read of the hibernate section of the reference guide on how to configure hibernate and use hibernate with spring. Next to that you should be using Spring your dao is seriously flawed.